# The building of two districts should be considered as two separate action or as one comprehensive action?

Tags: citadels

Suppose that one player is a *Scholar*, an *Architect*, a *Trader*, a *Seer* or any other character that can build more than one district per turn. Suppose also that the *Tax Collector* is one of the character used in this game.

The rule-book states that:

> When the Tax Collector is one of the characters in the game, players are charged a property tax for building districts. **Immediately after** a player builds a district, he places one gold from his stash on the Tax Collector’s character token. [...] If a player builds more than one district, he is charged the property tax for each district built. If a player has no gold remaining in his stash after building a district, he is not charged a tax. [...]

Suppose that our player has 10 golds and 2 district of cost 5. Can he build both districts and pay no gold to the *Tax Collector* or should he build only one district and pay one gold to the *Tax Collector*?

Or, in other words, can the building of more than one district be considered as a single action?

---

**Note** This question is concerning Citadels 2016 edition. However, a similar question could arise when playing the editions of 2000 and 2004 even if there isn't the *Tax Collector* character. So, if your answer isn't valid for all the three versions of the game, then please explicit the valid version(s).

Comment: You mean _composite_ action?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Yes. If I can build two or more districts as a single composite action then I could pay the Tax Collector after building all three of them (and in the case I’ve not enough money paying less than the full amount).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the game, I'm just pointing out that `complessive` does not seem to be an English word. You might want to edit it out of the title.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh It's Italian for comprehensive. I've edited the post to use the English word.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh My bad, you were right. Thanks to pointed it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tax Collector collects immediately after each one, as per the text you quote.

(Note: there may be at least one version of the rules whose section for the Tax Collector reads "one or more" and "at the end of the turn" instead. EDIT: found it: the original 2004 Dark City Expansion version said "If a player builds one or more districts in his city, that player must give you 1 gold at the end of his turn."  According to [this BGG post](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1615236/differences-original) , the Tax Collector was the only character whose card text changed in the 2016 edition ).

Comment: So, it depends on the base of the rule-book I’m using? Personally, I like the version with _immediately_ because allows to avoid the tax if there are no golds left and then collect golds with the power of characters and/or with the power of special districts.